# ifup eth0 timeout during boot

Tags: networking, boot, networkcard

I need to start `eth0` network interface during boot, but only if cable is plugged in. I have following in my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The problem is, when the cable is not plugged in, the computer still tries to reach the `dhcp` server and it takes long time to time out and eventually boot.

Is there some way to skip the `eth0` configuration if link is not detected?

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: did you tried to set static insted of dhcp, and put some static address, if this works for you

Comment: @vladeli - no, I need to use dhcp.

Answer (score 8):

You can modify the amount of time used to wait for the DHCP response by editing `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`:

```
#timeout 60
timeout 10
```

This will set a ten-second window of opportunity for the DHCP server to respond. You might want to experiment with the timeout speed. Or, you could disable `eth0` at startup by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
#auto eth0
```

Then, bring up `eth0` manually when you want it, with `sudo ifup eth0`.

Comment: the DHCP server is sometimes slow to respond. If I set the timeout too low, then my client will mistaken slow response for no response. If I set the timeout high enough, then I am back where I  have started. I know, I can detect if link is up with `ethtool eth0`. Is there no possibility (i.e. a ifup hook) to check if link is up?